# Why has my render got such a sharp light gradient in eevee?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I rendered as an EXR sequence with the DWAA codec in Eevee. It could have something to do with that or it might just be my monitor, I'm not sure.

[image: PNG]

EXR:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yapa4vja06x2ur0/Shot_20100.exr?dl=0

[image: Render settings]

Comment: Please embed your images directly into the question rather than making folks go to links which aren't likely to exist in future. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 3):

This is [banding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterization). It's common with 8-bit colour output and subtle gradients. Either enable [dithering in post-processing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/render/output/properties/post_processing.html#bpy-types-rendersettings-dither-intensity) or output to a 16-bit format (noting that monitors generally can't display all these colours and so you'll still see banding until you apply dithering).

This is part of your EXR after converting to 8-bit with dithering applied in GIMP - banding is much reduced:

[image: 8-bit image with dithering]

Comment: ..but shows up when the image is displayed resized. Click the link to get a better idea :)

Comment: @Nick I rendered it with a full colour depth (^see edit to original post^) so surely because it is a 32 bit colour depth it would be more than sufficient to avoid banding? Might be very wrong, just thought I'd ask.